# Lazy Initialisation with OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring

I have a little already working JBoss webapp, and a Lazy initialisation problem.
Therefore I was advised to investigate in Spring and use `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`.

Nevertheless I still get the error, hope you could help me?
What else do I have to change in my app to make use of the Spring OEM Filter?

My setup is like this:

```
@Entity
class Customer;

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
class DaoService {
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;
}

@Named
@RequestScoped
class CustomerFacade;
```

+jsf stuff.

```
[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: domain.Customer.customerList, no session or session was closed
```

I set it up like this:
web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<!-- Include this if you are using Hibernate -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring config -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
                org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, the example data source is just for proofs of concept! -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thats basically all the setup. And everything is working apart from the lazy loading problem.

Comment: make sure the OEMIV filter comes first in the filtering pipeline (before your app's main controller servlet/filter).

Comment: That's the full web.xml I posted. There are no filters or else before...

Comment: You are using JSF. Don't you declare the javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet servlet?

Comment: No I don't. It's just managed by JBoss Server automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't access old entities (for example serialized ones in the session in previous request).

Answer (score 4):

Is necessary to indicate in the init parameters EntityManager

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: Where is the filter mapping? for URL pattern? at least membersound has done it correctly