# Lazy Loading does not retrieve when required

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a User bean that references Department in this way:

```
@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", length = 2)
public String getDepartmentId() {
    return this.departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
public Department getDepartment() {
    return this.department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}
```

.. and in Department

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

When, in my javax.servlet.Filter implementation, I try to reference the Department bean from my User bean like this:

```
UserService userService = (UserService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userService");
User user = userService.getUser(userId);
user.setDepartmentName(user.getDepartment().getName());
```

I get this:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session

This is the userService.getUser():

```
public User getUser(String userId) throws ApplicationException {

    User user = null;
    try {
        user = userDAO.findById(userId);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        ApplicationException.handleThrowable(e, userId, this.getClass());
    }
    return user;
}
```

.. and userDAO.findById():

```
public User findById(String id) {

    return ( User )getSession().get( User.class, id );
}
```

I should also mention that I am using OpenSessionInViewFilter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

So can someone tell me please why the LazyInitializationException?

Thanks!

Btw I'm using Hibernate 3.6.10 and Spring 3.2.4

Comment: Does your session factory get called before the exception ?

Comment: why `singleSession` is set to `false`? it have look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html#setSingleSession(boolean))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring and hibernate: No Session found for current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298483/spring-and-hibernate-no-session-found-for-current-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having attached the OpenSessionInViewFilter source and put some stops in the getSession() and closeSession() methods, it became clear that it was not being used. Further searching revealed that the order of the filter-mappings in web.xml is significant in this respect. **Moving the filter-mapping for OpenSessionInViewFilter to before the one for my servlet filter solved the problem.**

Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an open session at that point, so the code has no way to reach the database.

I'm guessing you have a transaction on your UserService (usually you put it on the service layer) and since you're accessing the lazy property outside of the service layer, your transaction and session are closed.  By default, the session binds to a transaction.

Either:

- Put this code in the session as well
- Make sure all required fields are populated *before* you leave the transaction
- Make this code transactional (with propagation on the inner transaction)
- use OpenSessionInView (warning: here be dragons)

Comment: I do have a transaction on my UserService but I am using OpenSessionInView which on the whole works fine. I can reference not-yet-loaded beans on my Faces pages without a problem normally but every now and again I get a problem like this where it doesn't work. I guess what I'm trying to nail down is why it's happening in this particular case when OpenSessionInView is working 99% of the time. Maybe the way I'm accessing the service?

Comment: Maybe you're closing the session somewhere?  Use a debugger to check if the userservice you're retrieving is the real bean or the transaction proxy (the latter is what you want).  Then check if the current session is the same in and outside of the method (since you're using OSIV you want it to be the same)

Comment: Definitely is the proxy. How would I get a handle to the session inside and out of the method to check?

Comment: @NeilRichards you will need to inject the sessionfactory into your calling bean.  Then put a breakpoint in the calling beand and in the service.  Then add a watch on sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().  The memory location should be the same.  If that doesnt help,  you'll have to trace to hibernate.  We all have to go there sometimes :)  But then post the solution here.

Comment: The 'calling bean' is actually a servlet filter so can't inject. However if I use SpringApplicationContext.getBean() to get the sessionfactory I get it fine, but the getCurrentSession() throws a HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context. That would be understandable I think if there was no OpenSessionInViewFilter, but there is

Comment: if the calling bean is a servlet filter, are you sure the OSIV filter comes first?  Check the stack?  if it does come first, get the sources and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing singleSession parameter tor true in your configuration and look on that case [Lazy initialization problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304020/lazy-initialisation-with-openentitymanagerinviewfilter?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the singleSession parameter to true but I am still getting the same problem. Not sure what part of Lazy Initialization Problem you're referring to - it doesn't seem very similar