# Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

So I have this two classes:

**Sample**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sample")
public class Sample implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="sample_id")
private Long sample_id;
@Column(name="id")
private String id;
@Column(name="description")
private String description;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="dna_study_id")
private DNA_Study study;
...Getters and setters ...
```

**DNA_Study**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dna_study")
public class DNA_Study implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="dna_study_id")
private Long id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column(name="description")
private String description;
@Column(name="date")
private Date date;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "dna_study_id")
private List<Sample> samples;
```

I want to get all the DNA_Study from my database, having this **DAO**:

```
@Repository
public interface DNA_StudyDAO extends CrudRepository<DNA_Study, Long>{ }
```

and this **RestController**:

```
@RestController
public class AnalysisController {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/getanalysis")
    public ArrayList<DNA_Study> getAnalysis() {

        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        DNA_StudyDAO dao = context.getBean(DNA_StudyDAO.class);
        return (ArrayList<DNA_Study>) dao.findAll();
    }
```

As when I call it I get "**Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role**" I tried to modify my DAO so method findAll() changes to:

```
@Override
@Query("select d from DNA_Study d join fetch d.samples")
Iterable<DNA_Study> findAll();
```

using this no exception is throwed but calling method creates an infinite loop since creating a DNA_Study implies loading it's samples and each sample load it's DNA_Study etc. so it breaks. So I assume I will need to add an OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and undo the override to findAll(), tried adding to my SpringBootServletInitializer class :

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(Application.class);
    rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class);
    filter.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
    filter.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
}
```

But when I make the call I'm still getting "**failed to lazily initialize a collection of role**"

how should I properly add **OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter** ?

---

**EDIT**

class that extends **SpringBootServletInitializer** :

```
@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(GemDomusServerApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(Application.class);
        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
        filter.setInitParameter("entityManagerFactoryBeanName", "entityManagerFactory");
        filter.setInitParameter("flushMode", "auto");
        filter.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(GemDomusServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

**applicationContext.xml beans involved**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>**</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>**</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>**</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="jpaData"/>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally after trying this worked:
making Eager initialization booth collections (Sample and DNA_Study and changing AnalysisController to:

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/getanalysis")
    public JsonArray getAnalysis() {

        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        DNA_StudyDAO dao = context.getBean(DNA_StudyDAO.class);
        ArrayList<DNA_Study> result = (ArrayList<DNA_Study>) dao.findAll();
        JsonArrayBuilder datasourcesBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for(DNA_Study study : result) {
            datasourcesBuilder
            .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", study.getName())
                .add("description", study.getDescription())
                .add("size", String.valueOf(study.getSamples().size())));
        }
        return datasourcesBuilder.build();
}
```

Could not find a way of doing that with lazy initialization

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks very similar to this one  [Lazy Initialisation with OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304020/lazy-initialisation-with-openentitymanagerinviewfilter)

Another option, my preferred, is to call Hibernate.initialize(Object) inside your DAO or a Manager Wrapping your DAO annotated with @Transactional

Comment: So I should call findAll() and iterate over any element with Hiebernate.initialize(Object) ?

Comment: this query should be enough to force an EAGER fetch your samples collections "select d from DNA_Study d join fetch d.samples" but in case this doesn't work you can force this in the code by iterating object and calling Hibernate.initialize

Comment: But what I need is lazy initialisation. In the link they add a filter, so did I and didn't work.

Comment: Also doing ArrayList<DNA_Study> result = (ArrayList<DNA_Study>) dao.findAll();
  for(DNA_Study dna : result) {
   Hibernate.initialize(dna.getSamples());
  }
returns HibernateException "collection is not associated with any session"

Comment: This is working for me in my project. Give it a try. It force the initialization of the iterator.                                                                                                      "if (dna.getSamples().size() > 0)
dna.getSamples().iterator().hasNext();"